# Why does my DLL not require a DllMain function?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I just added a C++ Windows DLL project to a Visual Studio (2022) solution.  The wizard put a `DllMain` in there.  That jumped out at me; I didn't remember my other DLLs having `DllMain` functions;

Searching my code, it turns out that none of my 9 DLLs have DllMain functions.  Yet they all build and work fine.  I checked the project settings for all of these projects:

- None of them have the linker `/NOENTRY` option set.
- They all have `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` set.
- None of them have the linker  `/NODEFAULTLIB` option set
- They are certainly all DLLS.

So I commented out that DllMain in the new project I just added.  It still built just fine.

My knowledge is clearly out of date.   I thought a `DllMain` used to be required.  I remember years ago getting linker errors in my DLLs when I failed to add a `DllMain`.

So my questions are:

1. Why do my DLLs not require DllMain?  Is there some build setting I did not check?
2. Is there any downside to not having one?

(Note that these DLLS all export C++ classes.  None of them are resource DLLs.  All have been working fine for 6 years.  Some of them use thread-local storage.  Some of them have static variables inside of functions.  I always thought that using things like these necessitated a DllMain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The runtime library ("CRT" = C/C++ Runtime Library) provides the *real* DLL entry point `_DllMainCRTStartup`, that does things like initializing global variables before calling your `DllMain`.  There's documentation on MSDN that describes this:

- [DLLs and Visual C++ run-time library behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior)

Documentation of the linker `/ENTRY` option is also relevant:

- [`/ENTRY` (Entry-Point Symbol)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol)

There's also a library-provided weak symbol for your `DllMain`, so the call from the real entrypoint to `DllMain` doesn't fail at link time with an unresolved external.  From the first document above:

> By default, if you do not provide a `DllMain` function, Visual Studio provides one for you and links it in so that `_DllMainCRTStartup` always has something to call.

The things you mentioned like thread-local storage do require using the library-provided entrypoint; they'll break if you use the `/ENTRY` option to link.exe to replace the library entrypoint with your own or `/NOENTRY` to disable it.  None of them require anything to be done by the `DllMain` that the library entrypoint calls.

Comment: So if I am remembering needing to define  DllMain to make a DLL work is that just poor memory on my part?  I could have sworn that was the case.  But I haven't really monkeyed around with a DllMain for almost 20 years

Comment: @Joe: Writing your own `DllMain` has never been necessary if the library-provided behavior was good enough.

Comment: OK, then this entire question was a senior moment.  Thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: @Joe: I think what you may be remembering is behavior stemming from a .DEF file that the wizards used to create (before the `__declspec(dllexport)` system existed, exports had to be listed there).  If you removed any of the wizard-generated functions (for example `DllCanUnloadNow` or `DllRegisterServer`) from the C/C++ source code and didn't remove them from the .DEF file, you'd get link errors.